# Stripe - how add product on the connected account?

Tags: c#, .net, stripe-payments, payment

I try add payment method to my project where customer can buy product from other user. But i have problem because when i use it:

```
LineItems = new List<SessionLineItemOptions>
  {
    new SessionLineItemOptions
    {
      Price = "{{PRICE_ID}}",
      Quantity = 1,
    },
  },
  Mode = "payment",
  SuccessUrl = "https://example.com/success",
  CancelUrl = "https://example.com/cancel",
  PaymentIntentData = new SessionPaymentIntentDataOptions
  {
    ApplicationFeeAmount = 123,
  },
};

var requestOptions = new RequestOptions
{
  StripeAccount = "{{CONNECTED_ACCOUNT_ID}}",
};
var service = new SessionService();
Session session = service.Create(options, requestOptions);
```

PRICE_ID can't be price's on my main stripe account and i must create product and price on the connected account.
In the case of creating a product on the main account, I do it like this:

```
var options = new ProductCreateOptions
                {
                    Id = ProductId.ToString(),
                    Name = "Product_name",
                    DefaultPriceData = new ProductDefaultPriceDataOptions
                    {
                        UnitAmount = price,
                        Currency = "pln"
                    },
                    Expand = new List<string> { "default_price" },
                };
                _productService.Create(options);
```

How create product and price on the connected account with my api?

Answer (score 1):

The Stripe API has a [`Stripe-Account` header](https://stripe.com/docs/api/connected_accounts?lang=dotnet) where you can pass in the ID of one of your connected accounts to make the call as that account. In C# that would look like this:

```
                {
                    Id = ProductId.ToString(),
                    Name = "Product_name",
                    DefaultPriceData = new ProductDefaultPriceDataOptions
                    {
                        UnitAmount = price,
                        Currency = "pln"
                    },
                    Expand = new List<string> { "default_price" },
                    StripeAccount = "acct_123456789",
                };
                _productService.Create(options);
```

Comment: I don't have it. Error ProductCreateOptions does not contain a definition for StripeAccount. :/

Comment: I fount it. We must use requestOptions like this:
```
var requestOptions = new RequestOptions
                {
                    StripeAccount = stripeAccountId,
                };
                _productService.Create(options, requestOptions);
```